# Serializable Queue header only library

Tags: c++, c++11, queue, serialization

I was hoping someone could check the library I 'm working on to see if they could give any suggestions. My biggest issue right now is getting tuple to work with more than just the basic types and I also wanted to add exception safety; is this only necessary for the file save/load functions? I also still need to add the rule of 5 for this.

https://github.com/Salgat/SerializeQueue

```
//=====================================================================================================================================
//  The MIT License (MIT)
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Austin Salgat
//  
//  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files
//  (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify,
//  merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished
//  to do so, subject to the following conditions:
//  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
//  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES
//  OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE
//  LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR
//  IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
//=====================================================================================================================================

#pragma once
#ifndef __SERIALIZE_QUEUE__
#define __SERIALIZE_QUEUE__

#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <memory>
#include <fstream>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <utility>
#include <map>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <tuple>

namespace serq {
    /**
     * Returns a reversed tuple. (thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119048/reversing-a-c-tuple)
     */
    template<typename T, typename TT = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type, size_t... I>
    auto reverse_impl(T&& t, std::index_sequence<I...>) -> std::tuple<typename std::tuple_element<sizeof...(I) - 1 - I, TT>::type...> {
        return std::make_tuple(std::get<sizeof...(I) - 1 - I>(std::forward<T>(t))...);
    }

    template<typename T, typename TT = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>
    auto reverse(T&& t) -> decltype(reverse_impl(std::forward<T>(t), std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<TT>::value>())) {
        return reverse_impl(std::forward<T>(t), std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<TT>::value>());
    }

    template <class T>
    struct tag {};

    /**
     * FIFO queue that is able to convert back and forth from and to binary (serialized) data.
     */
    class SerializeQueue {
    private:
        std::vector<uint64_t> variable_lengths; // Used to store the lengths of variable sized objects
        std::stack<std::vector<unsigned char>> binary_data;

        std::vector<unsigned char> original_serialized_blob;
        std::vector<unsigned char> serialized_blob;

        // Helper methods
        /**
         * Adds the char blob to the serialized_blob.
         */
        inline void PushBlob(std::vector<unsigned char> const& char_blob) {
            for (unsigned char const character : char_blob) {
                serialized_blob.push_back(character);
            }
        }

        inline void PushBlob(std::vector<unsigned char> const& char_blob, int offset) {
            //for (unsigned char const character : char_blob) {
            for (int index = offset; index < char_blob.size(); ++index) {
                serialized_blob.push_back(char_blob[index]);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Pushes data directly to serialized_data.
         */
        inline void PushToSerializedBlob(uint64_t const data) {
            for (std::size_t index = 0; index < sizeof(data); ++index) {
                serialized_blob.push_back((data >> (index*8)) & 0xFF);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Returns uint64_t value at provided serialized_blob offset.
         */
        inline uint64_t const ReadSerializedBlob(int const offset) const {
            uint64_t data = 0x00;
            for (int index = sizeof(data)-1; index >= 0; --index) {
                unsigned char character = serialized_blob[index+offset];
                data |= static_cast<uint64_t>(character) << static_cast<uint64_t>(index*8);
            }

            return *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(&data);
        }

        inline uint64_t const ReadSerializedBlob(int const offset, std::vector<unsigned char> const& data_vector) const {
            uint64_t data = 0x00;
            for (int index = sizeof(data)-1; index >= 0; --index) {
                unsigned char character = data_vector[index+offset];
                data |= static_cast<uint64_t>(character) << static_cast<uint64_t>(index*8);
            }

            return *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(&data);
        }           

        inline void WriteToOffset(uint64_t const data, int const offset) {
            for (int index = 0; index < sizeof(data); ++index) {
                serialized_blob[index+offset] = (data >> (index*8)) & 0xFF;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Returns length of current variable length object (that is not yet popped).
         */
        inline uint64_t const GetVariableLength() const {
            auto offset_counter = ReadSerializedBlob(0);
            return ReadSerializedBlob((offset_counter)*8);
        }

        /**
         * Decrements offset counter for variable length variables.
         */
        inline void DecrementVariableLengthCounter() {
            auto offset_counter = ReadSerializedBlob(0);
            --offset_counter;
            WriteToOffset(offset_counter, 0x00);
        }

        /**
         * Template specialized overloads (tag section)
         */

        // Push Section -----------------------------------------------------------

        inline void push(tag<uint64_t>, uint64_t const data) {
            push(data);
        }

        inline void push(tag<unsigned int>, unsigned int const data) {
            push(data);
        }

        inline void push(tag<int>, int const data) {
            push(data);
        } 

        inline void push(tag<unsigned char>, unsigned char const data) {
            push(data);
        }

        inline void push(tag<float>, float const data) {
            push(data);
        }

        inline void push(tag<double>, double const data) {
            push(data);
        }

        inline void push(tag<std::string>, std::string const& data) {
            push(data);
        }

        // STL Containers

        template<class T1, class T2>
        inline void push(tag<std::pair<T1, T2>>, std::pair<T1, T2> const& data) {
            push(data);
        }

        template<class... Values, std::size_t... IndexSequence>
        void push_tuple(std::tuple<Values...> const& data, std::index_sequence<IndexSequence...>) {
            // Due to how the tuple is stored, it needs to be reversed (pop order is backwards).
            // Todo: A more efficient way to push or pop in reverse
            auto new_tuple = reverse(data);
            (int[]){ 0, (push(std::get<IndexSequence>(new_tuple)), 0)... };
        }

        template<class... Values>
        inline void push(tag<std::tuple<Values...>>, std::tuple<Values...> const& data) {

            push_tuple(data, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Values)>());
        }

        template<class T>
        inline void push(tag<std::vector<T>>, std::vector<T> const& data_vector) {
            push_vector(data_vector);
        }

        template<class T1, class T2>
        inline void push(tag<std::map<T1, T2>>, std::map<T1, T2> const& data_map) {
            push_map(data_map);
        }

        template<class T>
        inline void push(tag<std::queue<T>>, std::queue<T> data_queue) {
            push_queue(data_queue);
        }

        template<class T>
        inline void push(tag<std::stack<T>>, std::stack<T> data_stack) {
            push_stack(data_stack);
        }

        // Pop Section -----------------------------------------------------------

        template<class T>
        inline T const pop_generic() {
            uint64_t data = 0x00;
            for (int index = sizeof(data)-1; index >= 0; --index) {
                unsigned char character = serialized_blob.back();
                serialized_blob.pop_back();
                data |= static_cast<uint64_t>(character) << static_cast<uint64_t>(index*8);
            }

            return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data);
        }

        inline uint64_t const pop(tag<uint64_t>) {
            return pop_generic<uint64_t>();
        }

        inline unsigned int const pop(tag<unsigned int>) {
            return pop_generic<unsigned int>();
        }

        inline int const pop(tag<int>) {
            return pop_generic<int>();
        }

        inline unsigned char const pop(tag<unsigned char>) {
            return pop_generic<unsigned char>();
        }

        inline float const pop(tag<float>) {
            return pop_generic<float>();
        }

        inline double const pop(tag<double>) {
            return pop_generic<double>();
        }

        // STL Containers

        template<class T1, class T2>
        inline std::pair<T1, T2> const pop(tag<std::pair<T1, T2>>) {
            return pair_pop<T1, T2>();
        }

        template<class... Values>
        inline auto pop(tag<std::tuple<Values...>>) {
            return std::make_tuple<Values...>(std::move(pop<Values>())...);
        }

        template<class T>
        inline std::vector<T> const pop(tag<std::vector<T>>) {
            return vector_pop<T>();
        }

        template<class T1, class T2>
        inline std::map<T1, T2> const pop(tag<std::map<T1, T2>>) {
            return map_pop<T1, T2>();
        }

        template<class T>
        inline std::queue<T> const pop(tag<std::queue<T>>) {
            return queue_pop<T>();
        }

        template<class T>
        inline std::stack<T> const pop(tag<std::stack<T>>) {
            return stack_pop<T>();
        }

    public:
        SerializeQueue() {}

        /**
         * Clears queue completely.
         */
        void Clear() {
            variable_lengths.clear(); // Used to store the lengths of variable sized objects
            binary_data = std::stack<std::vector<unsigned char>>();

            original_serialized_blob.clear();
            serialized_blob.clear();
        }

        /**
         * Returns a vector of char which represents the binary state of the serialized data.
         * Data is stored in little-endian order (least significant byte in the smallest address).
         *
         * Note: vector is used because it automatically stores the size of the char blob.
         */
        std::vector<unsigned char> const Serialize() {
            serialized_blob.clear();

            // Create the header, outlined as follows (all entrys are 64 bits)
            //  - Address 0x00: Header length (this is decremented whenever variable data is popped)
            //    - Used to determine the length of a variable object, example for std::vector<int>
            //      uint64_t vector_length = current_variable_length(); // this function needs to read the first 8 bytes as a uint64_t
            //      decrement_variable_length();
            // Todo: Take the original_serialized_blob and use its header, modified, for the new serialized_blob

            // Get original header, and append new header data to it
            unsigned int original_header_length;
            if (original_serialized_blob.size() > 0) {
                original_header_length = ReadSerializedBlob(0x00, original_serialized_blob); // Multiply by 8 for the character length
            } else {
                original_header_length = 0;
            }
            unsigned int new_header_length = original_header_length + variable_lengths.size();
            PushToSerializedBlob(static_cast<uint64_t>(new_header_length));

            if (original_header_length > 0) {
                for (std::size_t index = 1*8; index < (original_header_length+1)*8; ++index) {
                    serialized_blob.push_back(original_serialized_blob[index]);
                }
            }
            for (std::size_t index = 0 ; index < variable_lengths.size(); ++index) {
                PushToSerializedBlob(variable_lengths[variable_lengths.size()-1-index]);
            }

            // Append original data minus the old header
            for (std::size_t index = (new_header_length+1)*8; index < original_serialized_blob.size(); ++index) {
                serialized_blob.push_back(original_serialized_blob[index]);
            }

            // Append the new data
            auto binary_data_copy = binary_data;
            while(!binary_data_copy.empty()) {
                auto const char_blob = binary_data_copy.top();
                binary_data_copy.pop();

                PushBlob(char_blob);
            }

            return serialized_blob;
        }

        /**
         * Stores a binary blob of the serialized data to the provided file name and returns the
         * character blob in a vector.
         */
        std::vector<unsigned char> const Serialize(std::string const& file_name) {
            Serialize();

            // Write char array to file
            std::ofstream output(file_name, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
            for (auto const& character : serialized_blob) {
                output.put(character);
            }

            return serialized_blob;
        }

        /**
         * Resets the values of this class object to whatever contents are in the provided binary blob.
         */
        void Deserialize(std::string const& file_name) {
            Clear();

            std::ifstream input(file_name, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
            char character;
            while(input.get(character)) {
                original_serialized_blob.push_back(static_cast<unsigned char>(character));
            }

            serialized_blob = original_serialized_blob;
            original_serialized_blob.clear();
        }

        /**
         * Generic push onto queue (calls one of the other specific implementations).
         * Useful because it enforces more explicit type storage.
         *
         * Note: Tag-dispatching is used to allow for STL template specializations
         */
        template<class T>
        void push(T data) {
            push(tag<T>(), data);
        }

        /**
         * Converts data to a character array and pushes it on top of the data stack.
         */
        void push(uint64_t const data) {
            std::vector<unsigned char> char_blob;
            for (std::size_t index = 0; index < sizeof(data); ++index) {
                char_blob.push_back((data >> (index*8)) & 0xFF);
            }

            binary_data.push(char_blob);
        }

        void push(unsigned int const data) {
            // Data is expanded to 64-bit for compatibility with both x64 and x32
            auto data_64bit = static_cast<uint64_t>(data);
            push(data_64bit);
        }

        void push(int const data) {
            auto data_64bit = static_cast<int64_t>(data);
            push(*reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(&data_64bit));
        }

        void push(unsigned char const data) {
            std::vector<unsigned char> char_blob = {data};
            binary_data.push(char_blob);
        }

        void push(float const data) {
            float data_copy = data;
            uint64_t data_64bit = 0x00;
            data_64bit |= *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(&data_copy);
            push(data_64bit);
        }

        void push(double const data) {
            double data_copy = data;
            if (sizeof(double) == 8) {
                push(*reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(&data_copy));
            } else {
                uint64_t data_64bit = 0x00;
                data_64bit |= *reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(&data_copy);
                push(data_64bit);
            }   
        }

        void push(char const* data) {
            std::vector<unsigned char> char_blob;
            char_blob.push_back('\0');
            for (std::size_t index = 0; data[index] != '\0'; ++index) {
                char_blob.push_back(data[index]);
            }

            binary_data.push(char_blob);
        }

        void push(std::string const& data) {
            char const* char_array = data.c_str();
            push(char_array);
        }

        /**
         * Push specializations for STL containers.
         */
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        template<class T1, class T2>
        void push(std::pair<T1, T2> const& data) {
            push<T1>(data.first);
            push<T2>(data.second);
        }

        template<class T>
        void push_vector(std::vector<T> const& data_vector) {
            for (auto const& data : data_vector) {
                push(data);
            }

            variable_lengths.push_back(data_vector.size());
        }

        template<class T1, class T2>
        void push_map(std::map<T1, T2> const& data_map) {
            std::size_t counter = 0;
            for (auto& entry : data_map) {
                push<T1, T2>(entry);
                ++counter;
            }

            variable_lengths.push_back(counter);
        }

        template<class T>
        void push_queue(std::queue<T> data_queue) {
            std::size_t counter = 0;
            while(!data_queue.empty()) {
                push<T>(data_queue.front());
                data_queue.pop();
                ++counter;
            }

            variable_lengths.push_back(counter);
        }

        template<class T>
        void push_stack(std::stack<T> data_stack) {
            // First reverse the stack (due to it being stored in reverse order)
            std::stack<T> stack_reversed;
            while(!data_stack.empty()) {
                stack_reversed.push(data_stack.top());
                data_stack.pop();
            }

            std::size_t counter = 0;
            while(!stack_reversed.empty()) {
                push<T>(stack_reversed.top());
                stack_reversed.pop();
                ++counter;
            }

            variable_lengths.push_back(counter);
        }

        /**
         * Depending on the size of the data type, removes from the char blob data to form data type.
         */
        template<class T>
        T const pop() {
            return pop(tag<T>());
        }

        template<class T1, class T2>
        std::pair<T1, T2> const pair_pop() {
            T1 first = pop<T1>();
            T2 second = pop<T2>();
            return std::pair<T1, T2>(first, second);
        }

        /**
         * Specialization of pop() for STL containers. All types supported by T pop are supported in the container.
         */
        template<class T>
        std::vector<T> const vector_pop() {
            std::vector<T> data_vector;
            auto length = GetVariableLength();
            for (std::size_t index = 0; index < length; ++index) {
                data_vector.push_back(pop<T>());
            }

            DecrementVariableLengthCounter();
            return data_vector;
        }

        template<class T1, class T2>
        std::map<T1, T2> const map_pop() {
            std::map<T1, T2> data_map;
            auto length = GetVariableLength();
            std::pair<T1, T2> entry;
            for (std::size_t index = 0; index < length; ++index) {
                entry = pop<std::pair<T1, T2>>();
                data_map.insert(entry);
            }

            DecrementVariableLengthCounter();
            return data_map;
        }

        template<class T>
        std::queue<T> const queue_pop() {
            std::queue<T> data_queue;
            auto length = GetVariableLength();
            T entry;
            for (std::size_t index = 0; index < length; ++index) {
                entry = pop<T>();
                data_queue.push(entry);
            }

            DecrementVariableLengthCounter();
            return data_queue;
        }

        template<class T>
        std::stack<T> const stack_pop() {
            std::stack<T> data_stack;
            auto length = GetVariableLength();
            T entry;
            for (std::size_t index = 0; index < length; ++index) {
                entry = pop<T>();
                data_stack.push(entry);
            }

            DecrementVariableLengthCounter();
            return data_stack;
        }
    };

    // Template specializations
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Specialization of pop() meant for std::string.
     * 
     * Note: Stored in the serial blob as a character array wrapped with a null terminator on both sides.
     */
    template<>
    std::string const SerializeQueue::pop<std::string>() {
        std::vector<unsigned char> char_array;
        for (char character = serialized_blob.back(); character != '\0'; character = serialized_blob.back()) {
            char_array.push_back(character);
            serialized_blob.pop_back();
        }
        serialized_blob.pop_back();

        // Create a c string that is the reverse
        char c_string[char_array.size()+1];
        for (int index = char_array.size(); index > 0; --index) {
            c_string[char_array.size() - index] = char_array[index-1];

        }
        c_string[char_array.size()] = '\0';

        return std::string(c_string);
    }
}   

/**
 * TODO:
 *  - Add support for raw binaries (character blobs that don't use null terminators).
 *  - std::map and other stl containers
 *  - Exception support.
 *      - A better approach may be to use asserts instead, for things like reading beyond the end of the char blob.
 *  - Use move semantics where appropriate to avoid extra copies
 */


#endif // SERIALIZE_QUEUE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three things that stand out to me:

### Returning by `const` value is detrimental to performance:

Probably the main issue I've spotted in your code. In a place such as this:

> ```
> inline int const pop(tag<int>) { ...
>            ^^^^^
> ```

The extra `const` is harmless, though it might produce a compiler warning depending on platform and settings, it will have no negative side effects.

When you are returning a complex object, however, such as in here:

> ```
> inline std::vector<T> const pop(tag<std::vector<T>>) { ...
>                       ^^^^^
> ```

You are implicitly throwing away the ability for the compiler to `move` the return value and elide the copy. A `const`-qualified object cannot be moved, because `move`ing alters the source object (makes it empty). In that case, you are likely to pay for a full deep copy of the vector just because it was declared as a `const` value.

Also refer to [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716330/purpose-of-returning-by-const-value) for more in-depth details on this specifically.

That being said, `const` is still very important to ensure single-assignment and on read-only input parameters. Return-by-value is probably the only place where it is now advised against its use.

### No need for `inline`:

When a method is already declared inside the body of a class, directly in the header file, `inline` is implicit (and also explicit to the reader, for obvious reasons). There is not actual need to supply the keyword in such cases.

### Names starting with `__` (double underscore) bare a restriction:

`__SERIALIZE_QUEUE__` qualifies as an identifier using a notation [reserved for the implementation and/or standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/1198654). Simply using `SERIALIZE_QUEUE_H` fixes this.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of helpful response I was hoping for. Thanks glampert, I committed all your suggestions to my project.